# Appending data to one cell in Excel using OleDb

Tags: c#, excel, append, oledb

Is there a way to append data to one cell in Excel using OleDb?

For example, let's say I have a cell that has the value "Help me" and I want to append " Stack Overflow" to that cell. How would I do this? The only thing I could think of would be some use of the UPDATE command but I'm not really seeing how to use it in this way.

By the way, I'm using c# and Excel 2003 if it matters. And yes, I want to use OleDb, not a third party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using OleDb.